# Google sheet query renders numbers as text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to query multiple sheet importrange

```
=query({IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T"); IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T")},"select * where Col7 is not null",0)
```

Issue is query rendering a column 10(say column T) which consist of text and numbers as text only.

i am using below formula to further filter based on numeric value but doest work because of previous **query importrange issue**

=FILTER('Sheet'!C3:Q,'Sheet'!L3:L <=0)

Answer (score 0):

you can run lambda on it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(x*1, x))(
 QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T")},
 "where Col7 is not null", 0)))
```

Comment: Hi
for certain reasons lambda is creating other hurdles, i ll better stay away from that,


also lambda didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of FILTER and INDEX, "getting rid" of QUERY:

```
=FILTER({IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T"); IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T")},INDEX({IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T"); IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T")},,7)<>"")
```

Or, the same written with LAMBDA:

```
=LAMBDA(range,FILTER(range,INDEX(range,,7)<>""))
({IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T"); IMPORTRANGE("sheet url", "Student List!E4:T")})
```

Comment: i personally avoid lambda as it creates further importrange issues and are also slow. Filter worked fine for my case
thanks @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("insertidhere","'Student List'!E4:T");IMPORTRANGE("insertidhere","'Student List'!E4:T")},"select * where Col16 is not null")`
```

I made sample data to check, and it worked for me.
See screenshots below;
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1qN7.jpg (With Query Function)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOnn.jpg (Student List 1)
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVJ2.jpg (Student List 2)